# Pushing .txt values into vector

Tags: c++, vector

I've been trying to figure out how to push things from a .txt into a vector and I haven't quite been successful, so I've strayed from my assignment and created a simple code to learn it.

I tried to find a similar post on here but I couldn't, so here's my code:

This is what's in the text file:

```
32 34 5 6 243 2341 234 213 24 123 12354 124 432 12
```

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

vector <int> numbers;
int val;
int newval = 50;

  ifstream file ("text.txt");
   if ( file.is_open())
   {
       for ( int i = 0; i < newval ; i++)
       {
            numbers.push_back(val);
       }
   }else{
       cout << "unable to open file."<<endl;
   }

      for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
      }

 return 0;
}
```

What the code is doing is printing 50 zeros. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and any insight would be much appreciated! thank you.

P. S - in the initial for loop I was going to do:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.size() ; i++)
   {
        numbers.push_back(val);
   }
```

but that didn't make any sense to me because the vector is initially empty. If that's what I'm supposed to do, please explain. Thanks.

Comment: You do realize that you're never actually reading anything from that file, right? You open it, and check to see if it's open, but you never read from it...

Comment: Also, where does the 50 come from? Instead of hard coding in a read limit, you sould check the `fstream` each iteration to make sure the `eof`(end of file) flag isn't set.

Comment: the hard set number is because I know what's in the .txt. I wasn't sure how to keep the for loop going if I didn't have a number larger than i..
 what you're suggesting is a

 while ( ! eof.text) { 
    read items in text and put in vector
}

correct?

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm blind, you're never assigning a value to `val`.

If that is the case, you're getting 0s because that's the default value for `int`s.

To fix this, you'll need to actually assign a read value to `val` before adding it to `numbers`. Also note that it will be read as a `string` most likely, so you'll have to convert it to an `int` before it can be assigned to `val`; but that's it's own set of problems.

Comment: so every time you're trying to push a .txt into a vector everything in the .txt converted into a string?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on how you read it. You could use `file >> val` inside the loop to read each number directly; delimited by the spaces. The problem with this approach is if you accidentally try to read a non-`int` into `val`, the stream fails and does undesirable things until you reset it. I usually read it in using `getline` (or some other function that reads in a chuck of text), and check it before trying to convert it. Once you start storing larger structures of data, the stream operators (`<<` and `>>`) make reading and writing a lot easier.

Comment: I tried get line, it seems to work with strings only. I did forget to include a read, which shows my inexperience. when you say 'delimited by the spaces' , what do you mean?

Comment: @SwizzleStix617 `getline` returns a `string`; in your case, it would return `32 34 5 6 243 2341 234 213 24 123 12354 124 432 12`. You need to go over the string, and "cut" it on the spaces, then convert each piece into an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

So, After I receiving help from community members here ( carcigenicate and twalberg) I've resolved all problems with the code, and I'm posting it below to help anyone else with this kind of question.

This is the original text file:

```
32 34 5 6 243 2341 234 213 24 123 12354 124 432 12
```

Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

vector <int> numbers;
int val=0;


  ifstream file ("text.txt");
   if ( file.is_open())
   {
     while  (! file.eof())
       {
       while (file >> val){
            numbers.push_back(val);
       }
     }
   }else{
       cout << "unable to open file."<<endl;
    }
      for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
      }

file.close();
 return 0;
}
```

What prints as output:

```
32
34
5
6
243
2341
234
213
24
123
12354
124
432
12
```

Thank you community!